# How to force Mathematica to simplify expression with Dirac Delta distribution?

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, output

I would like to make Mathematica print

```
DiracDelta[a x]
```

as

```
1/Abs[a] DiracDelta[x]
```

Is there any way to do this for any a?

Comment: Why do not you introduce a rule like `rule = DiracDelta[a_ *x] :> 1/Abs[a]*DiracDelta[x]`. Then `DiracDelta[b*x] /. rule` returns `DiracDelta[x]/Abs[b]`.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch - I recommend that you make sure that `a` is not a function of `x`, e.g., `rule = DiracDelta[a_?(FreeQ[#, x] &)*x] :> 1/Abs[a]*DiracDelta[x];`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, You are right, of course, but that's what OP implicitly assumes, according to his question. Otherwise, he would have asked about a more general expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loop over the real-valued roots of the argument of the $\delta$-function:

```
rule = DiracDelta[f_?(Not@*FreeQ[x])] :>
       With[{roots = SolveValues[f == 0, x, Reals]}, 
         Total[DiracDelta[x - #]/Abs[D[f, x] /. x -> #] & /@ roots]];
```

Test cases:

```
DiracDelta[a x] /. rule
(*    DiracDelta[x]/Abs[a]    *)

DiracDelta[x^2 - 2] /. rule
(*    DiracDelta[-Sqrt[2] + x]/(2 Sqrt[2]) +
      DiracDelta[Sqrt[2] + x]/(2 Sqrt[2])       *)

DiracDelta[E^x - 1] /. rule
(*    DiracDelta[x]    *)

DiracDelta[x^2 + 2] /. rule
(*    0    *)
```

**Warning**: does not work with multiple roots!

### update: variable-specific rule

We must be able to specify the variable instead of always using `x` as the integration variable:

```
δsimpl[var_] = 
  DiracDelta[f_?(Not@*FreeQ[var])] :>
    With[{roots = SolveValues[f == 0, var, Reals]},
      Total[DiracDelta[var - #]/Abs[D[f, var] /. var -> #] & /@ roots]];

DiracDelta[a x] /. δsimpl[x]
(*    DiracDelta[x]/Abs[a]    *)

DiracDelta[a x] /. δsimpl[a]
(*    DiracDelta[a]/Abs[x]    *)
```

Comment: Just adding a reference for those that might not be familiar with the formula above: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function or https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html